# Hide columns / rows for myself only not other users

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to hide rows or columns in a Google Spreadsheet without affecting their visibility for other users in the same spreadsheet, in the same way, you can filter using filter views which are only visible to the user who activated them?

Answer (score 3):

Such functionality isn't supported. Best you can do is to create a duplicate of the sheet and lock it for yourself (then hide it or hide rows & columns).

Also, you can scrape a whole sheet by creating a new spreadsheet and then use **`=IMPORTRANGE`** and then hide all the stuff you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide *rows* just for yourself in a sense by creating a filter view that hides the rows you're not interested in.  Others will be able to see & use the filter view, but it won't be their default view unless they choose it to be.

Hiding columns doesn't seem to be possible with this method as of October 2019.